# Installing software to another root

Tags: software-installation

I am running Ubuntu 15.10 32-bit on my computer. I am building a minimal kernel + busybox system from inside Ubuntu. I can already boot that system and run all busybox tools from it. But now I want to go further: I want to install the X Window System and a tiny window manager (probably IceWM). But I do not have internet connection in my minimal system yet and my computer is very, very slow, so compiling X from source is a big pain. My best bet is to use APT to download the X Window System and all its dependencies from Ubuntu repositories and install it to my minimal system's root filesystem, which is in /dev/sda2 (Ubuntu is in /dev/sda1). Is there a way to install packages with apt-get (or even dpkg, if needed) to another root, including all dependencies/libs?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you dual-booting with GRUB? Why don't you have internet connectivity from within your minimal system?

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to have internet connectivity from /dev/sda1, the approach I would try first is:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
sudo chroot /mnt
  apt-get update
  apt-get install xorg icewm
  exit
sudo umount /mnt
```